# How do I get EOT to work on IF ELSE statement in bash?

Tags: bash, proxy, environment-variables, eof, heredoc

I'm trying to make a script that enables proxy settings if the /etc/environment file is currently empty and disables the settings if the file has text. I've written some code but not sure why the /etc/environment file is not being edited. I have blanked out the actual proxies I am using. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash

        if [ -s /etc/environment ]
        then
            cat<<EOT >> /etc/environment
            http_proxy="blank"
            https_proxy="blank"
            ftp_proxy="blank"
            export http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy
            EOT
        else
            > /etc/environment
        fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also move the here document to the `if` statement itself.

```
if [ -s /etc/environment ]; then
  cat
fi <<EOT >> /etc/environment
http_proxy="blank"
https_proxy="blank"
ftp_proxy="blank"
export http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy
EOT
```

although if the `if` statement *itself* is indented, you'll still want to know how to indent the here document as Cyrus explains.

Answer (score 5):

Use `<<-` instead of `<<` if you want to indent the end token `EOT` or move `EOT` to first column.

Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: shellcheck is useful. It showed me the space after EOF and was able to fix the issue. Thanks.